# Swift error: index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

i'm working on my tableView and just now i implemented the function to delete the rows, but after i delete a row the app crash with this error (fatal error: index out of range)

```
struct User {

        var name: String
        var images: UIImage
        var coordinate : (Double , Double)
        var type: String
        var address: String
    }


      var users = [User]()




override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            rows = 0
            tableView.reloadData()
            insertRowsMode3()
    }

        @IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: Any) {

            rows = 0
            tableView.reloadData()
            insertRowsMode3()
        }

        func insertRowsMode2() {

            for i in 0..<users.count {
                insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: users[i])
            }            
        }

        func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:User) {

            let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

            rows = ind + 1
          tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
        }        

        func insertRowsMode3() {

            rows = 0            
            insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
        }

        func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {

            let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)                        
            rows = ind + 1                       
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)                        

            guard ind < users.count-1 else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {                
                self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
            }
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {           
            return 1
        }        

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {            
            return rows
        }

        public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

            let user = users[indexPath.row]

            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            cell.myImage.image = user.images
            cell.myLabel.text = user.name
            cell.myTypeLabel.text = user.type
            return (cell)
        }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
            })

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: users[indexPath.row])

        }

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 100
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

                users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.reloadData()

            }           
        }
```

this is the part of the code of my tableView, i think i know why the application go in crash but i don't know how to solve this problem, what i can do?

Comment: hi, in this line, where does the var users come from?users.remove(at: indexPath.row)

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection` rather than `return rows` return `return users.count`. Manual calculation of number of rows is quite error-prone.

Comment: @S.Wei right! i edited the question

Comment: @bero did vadian answer helps?

Comment: @S.Wei no still not working

Comment: yes @vadian's comment is right. you have to update to users.count

Comment: @bero btw DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.20) {                
                self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
            } hold up the main thread is not a good choice tho

Comment: @vadian now it work, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your `numberOfRowsInSectionas` rather than `return rows` return `return users.count` as per @vadian's comment.
and 
    update delete code with this

```
users.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: if i update return rows with return users.count the app go in crash when the view load

Comment: yes, because tablview delegate are called due to delegate and datasource connected in nib but your array "users" have no data. pls remove delegate and datasource connection from nib and add them before tableView.reloadData()  and call these methods when you have data in "users" array or array count > 0.